# list all files in multiple directories

Tags: bash, directory, ls

I would like to list all files in a certain directory, and list them with their full path.

I have a series of directories like this:

```
user.newskims.131017222704/
user.newskims.131017222741/
user.newskims.131017222822/
user.newskims.131017222949/
```

If I do

```
ls user.newskims.131017222*
```

The output has lines like this which I want to eliminate:

```
user.newskims.131017222822:
```

It also doesn't give the full path. Is there a way to make it list all of the files inside, and only those files and no additional rows, and with the full path?

Comment: `find user.newskims.131017222*`?

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work because it will also list the directories, and not just the files in the directories.

Comment: `find user.newskims.131017222* -type f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list file with *full path* of a given directory using `printf`:

```
printf "$PWD%s\n" user.newskims.131017222/*
```

Comment: This doesn't do the trick, I have to support wildcard directory names as there may be more than one directory containing the files I am interested in and the whole point is to avoid having to do the directories one by one.

Comment: You can always do `printf "$PWD%s\n" user.newskims.131017*/*` command